# FPGA pins driven high at power-up ‒ what can I do to get around this?

Tags: fpga, lattice

I have a board that uses a Lattice XP2-8 (BGA256, in case it makes any difference).

Some FPGA pins are connected directly to LEDs with positive logic.  That is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3UYle.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At power-up, the LED goes super-bright for a tiny fraction of a second (very very short, but very ***very*** obvious).

This is already in a PCB, manufactured and populated, etc., so I cannot change the circuit.  I tried configuring the pin (in Lattice Diamond, spreadsheet view) to pull-down, but it made no difference.

My question is:  is there anything that I can do at the HDL or LatticeDiamond level that would allow me to get around this?  (basically, I need to avoid the LED to be ON until the FPGA is configured and operating)

Comment: I've not used them, but isn't there a specification in the datasheet with respect to holding the I/O pin driver circuitry in a high impedance state during POR and then during initial boot/configuration of the device? I don't want to take the time to haul through them myself. But is that kind of information missing? (I was of course tempted to just say, *when using Lattice just ground all the pins to be safe*. But of course I then decided not to write any of that. ;)

Comment: At what stage are the outputs going high? Power up, during config or when your logic is running? Load up a bitstream that has the pins uncommitted or as inputs. See what happens. If there!s no flash, then that suggests it might be your logic.

Comment: Usually power up sequencing sends IOs of FPGA to high impedance.

Comment: I don't know Lattice but there is some often some flag at the start of configuration bitstream that say how to handle unused IOs (some part can use these as extra grounds for example). But before the start of load you can't really do anything, the real fix is to the hardware.

Comment: @jonk ‒ The datasheet explicitly state that all IO pins are maintained at high-impedance until the power supply voltage is high enough to guarantee reliable operation.  However, that says nothing about configuration (loading LUTs from internal flash, etc.).  I see nothing about that.  There is one pin, TOE (OE for Output Enable) that can be used to disable all IO pins (i.e., set them to high-impedance), but I never considered making use of TOE, so I just hard-wired a pull-up resistor to VCCCORE.

Comment: @Cal-linux Do you see that oversight now as a mistake? Can that be used during configuration, and perhaps just a little longer -- long enough for internal equilibrium to complete, to solve the current problem? If so, then there was a mechanism available. It just wasn't used. Is that about the summary of it? (Aside from the fact that there's no doc on I/O pin state during configuration.)

Comment: @Kartman ‒ I will try your suggestion.  However, the pins ultimately need to be outputs. I want to light the LED with a PWM type of signal, to do have a "dimmer" effect.  So, my top module has: `assign led_g1 = (counter[16:10] < intensity);`, where `intensity` is set to all-zeros by a (synchronous) reset signal, and `led_g1` is defined as `output wire led_g1;`.  Sounds like this could be the cause (after the logic starts, this intensity or counter registers may have weird values?)  What could be an approach to tackle this issue?  Configure the output as tri-state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the design to make the LED pin an I/O with tri-state, then use a delayed clock to enable the output mode after some time. The idea is to make the pin an input immediately after configuration, then after a small time switch the pin to output mode.

Do not allow the synthesizer optimize away the input from the LED pin (making it just an output pin), maybe connect it to an unused pin. To create the delay, just create a counter that increments on your system clock.

Comment: This works, yes, although it seems like in this particular case it wasn't necessary; just assigning the LED port to a reg, instead of to a logic expression, that eliminated the problem.  I did resort to the tri-state bidirectional pin for a different LED that was also giving me a hard time.